# GLSL Syntax error: "in" parse error

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, parse-error

I'm trying to use shaders in my program but i'm getting very strange error...

```
Vertex shader failed to compile with the following error
ERROR: 0:6: error(#132) Syntax error: "in" parse error
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

I thought the problem was with file reading, but after trying many ways of that it's still not working.

So here is my code:

```
bool ShaderProgram::LoadShaderFile(const char* shader_path, GLuint& shader_id)
{
    ifstream oFileStream(shader_path);
    if(oFileStream)
    {
        // Load shader code
        string sShaderSource;
        sShaderSource.assign((istreambuf_iterator<char> (oFileStream) ), istreambuf_iterator<char> () );

        // Forward shader code to OGL
        const GLchar* chShaderSource = sShaderSource.c_str() + '\0';
        printf("%s", chShaderSource);
        glShaderSource(shader_id, 1, (const GLchar**) &chShaderSource, NULL);


        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;

}
```

And my shaders:

```
// shader.vs
// Vertex Shader
#version 330

in vec3 vVertex
in vec3 vColor

smooth out vec4 vVaryingColor;

void main()
{
    vVaryingColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(vVertex, 1.0);
}


// shader.fs
// Fragment Shader
#version 330

smooth in vec4 vVeryingColor;
out vec4 vVaryingColor;

void main()
{
    vFragColor = vVaryingColor;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the semicolons at the end of the `in` lines.

You have:

```
in vec3 vVertex
in vec3 vColor
```

You should have:

```
in vec3 vVertex;
in vec3 vColor;
```

Comment: You are right, thank you!
I also missnamed output vector in frag shader.
Thats what happens, when you copy-paste code from many sources...

Comment: @user2843974 Also, be aware that some GPUs don't like having comments before the `#version` directive. So that could also in some cases be the reason a Shader couldn't be compiled.

Comment: Indeed, `#version` should be on the first line. Some versions of GLSL allow comments before it (e.g. GLSL ES 1.0) while others mandate that it has to be the first line ***period*** (e.g. GLSL ES 3.0). I would stick to placing it on the first line, because line ending and white space rules may become stricter as version numbers increase, and you want the pre-processor to parse the version directive before making any assumptions about what character(s) terminate single-line comments. See: GLSL ES 3.0 [Section 12.44](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.4.pdf)